Python scipy.optimize gives wrong answer, how to deal with semidefinite positive condition?
The goal is to calculate an optimization problem using python scipy.optimize.
Suppose C is a given 4-dimension matrix (in the code I use a random matrix to denote that). The optimized variables are A0 and B0 which are 2-dimension symmetric matrices. The constraints are I+A0, I-A0, I+B0, I-B0 are semidefinite positive, where I is 2-dimension identity matrix. The objective function is max Tr((A0 ⊗ B0)C), where ⊗ is the Kronecker Product.
The code is as follows:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
np.set_printoptions(precision = 8, suppress=True)
def objective_function(x, C):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))  
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    D00 = np.kron(A0,B0)
    return -np.trace(D00 @ C)
C = np.random.rand(4, 4)

A0_initial = np.zeros((2,2))
B0_initial = np.zeros((2,2))
initial_guess = np.hstack([A0_initial.flatten(), B0_initial.flatten()])

def constraint_func1(x):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    return  min(np.linalg.eigvals(np.eye(2) - A0))
def constraint_func2(x):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    return  min(np.linalg.eigvals(np.eye(2) + A0))
def constraint_func3(x):
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    return  min(np.linalg.eigvals(np.eye(2) - B0))
def constraint_func4(x):
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    return  min(np.linalg.eigvals(np.eye(2) + B0))
constraint1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_func1}
constraint2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_func2}
constraint3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_func3}
constraint4 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_func4}
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, args=(C,), constraints=[constraint1,constraint2,constraint3,constraint4])
A0_optimal = result.x[:4].reshape((2, 2))
B0_optimal = result.x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
A0_optimal = A0_optimal + A0_optimal.T
B0_optimal = B0_optimal + B0_optimal.T
print("C",C)
print(A0_optimal)
print(B0_optimal)
print(-result.fun)

The answer is always A0=B0= zero matrix, which is obviously wrong.  Why is the case? Is the scipy able to solve the constraint like this: min(np.linalg.eigvals(np.eye(2) - A0)) > 0? If not, what tools in python are recommended to solve the semidefinite positve conditions for matrix? (I tried cvxpy, but it doesn't support the kronecker product of two matrix variables because it is not convex)

Where is your objective function?

@jared I've added

Scipy minimization algorithms requires constraints to be differentiable. Your constraints are probably not because of the min function.

@jlandercy Is there any method to express the semidefinite positive condition by scipy?

It seems you have at least two key points to address:

Constraints must be somehow differentiable;
Initial guess must be different from np.zeros((2, 2)).

Let's adapt your MCVE:
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg, optimize

np.random.seed(123)

def objective(x, C):
    A0 = x[:4].reshape((2, 2))  
    B0 = x[4:8].reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    B0 = B0 + B0.T
    D00 = np.kron(A0, B0)
    return - np.trace(D00 @ C)

C = np.random.rand(4, 4)

We change initial guess for np.eye(2):
A0_initial = np.eye(2)
B0_initial = np.eye(2)
initial_guess = np.hstack([A0_initial.ravel(), B0_initial.ravel()])

We rewrite the constraint function to be somehow more smooth and eventually differentiable:
def constraint(x, sign=+1.):
    A0 = x.reshape((2, 2))
    A0 = A0 + A0.T
    U, s, Vt = linalg.svd(np.eye(2) + sign * A0)
    return np.min(np.sign(s)) * np.prod(np.abs(s))

Then your constraints can be translated as:
constraints = [
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: constraint(x[:4], sign=-1.)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: constraint(x[:4], sign=+1.)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: constraint(x[4:8], sign=-1.)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: constraint(x[4:8], sign=+1.)},
]

And the optimization goes as follow:
result = optimize.minimize(objective, initial_guess, args=(C,), constraints=constraints)
#  message: Optimization terminated successfully
#  success: True
#   status: 0
#      fun: -1.0327977281822147e+17
#        x: [ 6.132e+07  5.258e+07  5.258e+07  6.376e+07  4.866e+07
#             5.773e+07  5.773e+07  5.337e+07]
#      nit: 5
#      jac: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
#             0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
#     nfev: 45
#     njev: 5

This example shows how to smooth your constraints, but I will no say it satisfactory as it is very sensitive to initial conditions and does not work for any random matrix.

Does this work for the I-A0 constraint? I find that when I compute the eigenvalues of I-A0, some are negative. e.g. linalg.eigvalsh(np.eye(2) - 1 * result.x[:4].reshape((2,2)))

@NickOdell The OP explicitly stated in its code the matrix is the sum of itself and its transpose. I kept it as this but it might be something to develop.
